# Difference between Synchronization Context and Dispatcher

Tags: c#, .net

I am using `Dispatcher` to switch to UI thread from external like this

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(myAction);
```

But I saw on some forums people have advised to use `SynchronizationContext` instead of `Dispatcher`.

```
SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(myAction,null);
```

What is the difference between them and why `SynchronizationContext` should be used?.

Comment: Which forum and what were their arguments?

Comment: maybe a dumb question but what namespace is "Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(myAction);" comming from?? sorry I'm new to this!

Answer (score 41):

They both have similar effects, but `SynchronizationContext` is more generic.

`Application.Current.Dispatcher` refers to the WPF dispatcher of the application, and using `Invoke` on that executes the delegate on the main thread of that application.

`SynchronizationContext.Current` on the other hand returns different implementations of depending on the current thread. When called on the UI thread of a WPF application it returns a `SynchronizationContext` that uses the dispatcher, when called in on the UI thread of a WinForms application it returns a different one.

You can see the classes inheriting from `SynchronizationContext` in [its MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.SynchronizationContext(v=vs.110).aspx): [WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.windowsformssynchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) and [DispatcherSynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchersynchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx).

---

One thing to be aware about when using `SynchronizationContext` is that it returns the synchronization context of the **current** thread. If you want to use the synchronization context of another thread, e.g. the UI thread, you have to first get its context and store it in a variable:

```
public void Control_Event(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var uiContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    Task.Run(() => 
    {
        // do some work
        uiContext.Post(/* update UI controls*/);
    }
}
```

This does not apply to `Application.Current.Dispatcher`, which always returns the dispatcher for the application.

Comment: Small note - Task.ContinueWith lets you schedule a continuation on the ui without having to store the context manually http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331262/task-continuation-on-ui-thread

Comment: @Gusdor Sure, but the point is to show an example of `SynchronizationContext`.

Comment: @Gusdor, in the example you linked, a new task has to be created first. How do you use `Task.ContinueWith()` without a task to continue?

Comment: @KyleDelaney An existing task is a requirement of `ContinueWith`. Are you trying to solve a specific problem? Maybe a new question would be best.

Comment: Well I'm pointing out why your suggestion doesn't work as a replacement for this usage of `SynchronizationContext`.

Comment: There's also the ASP.NET synchronization context (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659851/aspnetsynchronizationcontext)

Answer (score 25):

When using `WPF`, the `SynchronizationContext.Current` object is of type `DispatcherSynchronizationContext` which is actually just a wrapper around the `Dispatcher` object and the `Post` and `Send` methods just delegate to `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` and `Dispatcher.Invoke`.

So even if you decide to use `SynchronizationContext` I think you end up calling dispatcher behind the scenes.

Besides I think it is a bit cumbersome to use `SynchronizationContext` as you have to pass a reference to the current context to all threads that need to call into your UI.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/Threading/DispatcherSynchronizationContext.cs

Comment: As explain in other answers, using `SynchronizationContext` instead of `Dispatcher` enables to abstract the UI from the logic, helps mocking the UI when unit testing and better fits with MVVM

Answer (score 22):

While the differences have been pointed out, I don't really see that reason for choosing one over another explicitly spelled out here. So perhaps it would help to explain what problem the **`SynchronizationContext`** object is trying to solve in the first place:

1. It provides a way to queue a unit of work to a context. Notice that this isn't thread specific, and so we avoid the problem of thread affinity.
2. Every thread has a "current" context, but that context might be shared across threads i.e. a context is not necessarily unique.
3. Contexts keep a count of outstanding asynchronous operations. This count is often, but not always incremented/decremented on capture/queuing.

So to answer your question of which one to choose, it would seem just from the criteria above that using the `SynchronizationContext` would be preferable to the `Dispatcher`.

But there are even more compelling reasons to do so:

- Separation of concerns

By using the `SynchronizationContext` to handle executing code on the UI thread, you can now easily separate your operations from the display via decoupled interface(s). Which leads to the next point:

- Easier unit testing

If you have ever tried to mock an object as complex as the `Dispatcher` versus the `SynchronizationContext`, which has far fewer methods to deal with, you will quickly come to appreciate the far simpler interface offered by the `SynchronizationContext`.

- IoC and Dependency Injection

As you have already seen, the `SynchronizationContext` is implemented across many UI frameworks: WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET, etc. If you write your code to interface to one set of APIs, your code becomes more portable and simpler to maintain as well as test.

You don't need to even inject a context object... you can inject any object with an interface that matches the methods on the context object, including proxies.

***By way of example:***

*Note: I have left out exception handling to make the code clear.*

Suppose we have a WPF application that has a single button. Upon clicking that button, you will start a long process of asynchronous work tasks interlaced with UI updates, and you need to coordinate IPC between the two.

Using WPF and the traditional Dispatch approach, you might code something like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Start a long series of asynchronous tasks using the `Dispatcher` for coordinating
/// UI updates.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void Start_Via_Dispatcher_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  // update initial start time and task status
  Time_Dispatcher.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
  Status_Dispatcher.Text = "Started";

  // create UI dont event object
  var uiUpdateDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

  // Start a new task (this uses the default TaskScheduler, 
  // so it will run on a ThreadPool thread).
  Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
  {
    // We are running on a ThreadPool thread here.

    // Do some work.
    await Task.Delay(2000);

    // Report progress to the UI.
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
      Time_Dispatcher.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");

      // signal that update is complete
      uiUpdateDone.Set();
    });

    // wait for UI thread to complete and reset event object
    uiUpdateDone.WaitOne();
    uiUpdateDone.Reset();

    // Do some work.
    await Task.Delay(2000); // Do some work.

    // Report progress to the UI.
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
      Time_Dispatcher.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");

      // signal that update is complete
      uiUpdateDone.Set();
    });

    // wait for UI thread to complete and reset event object
    uiUpdateDone.WaitOne();
    uiUpdateDone.Reset();

    // Do some work.
    await Task.Delay(2000); // Do some work.

    // Report progress to the UI.
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
      Time_Dispatcher.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");

      // signal that update is complete
      uiUpdateDone.Set();
    });

    // wait for UI thread to complete and reset event object
    uiUpdateDone.WaitOne();
    uiUpdateDone.Reset();
  },
  CancellationToken.None,
  TaskCreationOptions.None,
  TaskScheduler.Default)
    .ConfigureAwait(false)
    .GetAwaiter()
    .GetResult()
    .ContinueWith(_ =>
    {
      Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
      {
        Status_Dispatcher.Text = "Finished";

        // dispose of event object
        uiUpdateDone.Dispose();
      });
    });
}
```

This code works as intended, but has the following drawbacks:

1. The code is tied to the WPF **`Application`** **`Dispatcher`** object. This makes this difficult to unit test and abstract.
2. The need for an external **`ManualResetEvent`** object for synchronizing between threads. This should immediately set off a code smell, since this now depends on another resource that needs to be mocked.
3. Difficulty in managing object lifetime for said same kernel object.

Now, lets try this again using the **`SynchronizationContext`** object:

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void Start_Via_SynchronizationContext_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  // update initial time and task status
  Time_SynchronizationContext.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
  Status_SynchronizationContext.Text = "Started";

  // capture synchronization context
  var sc = SynchronizationContext.Current;

  // Start a new task (this uses the default TaskScheduler, 
  // so it will run on a ThreadPool thread).
  Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
  {
    // We are running on a ThreadPool thread here.

    // Do some work.
    await Task.Delay(2000);

    // Report progress to the UI.
    sc.Send(state =>
    {
      Time_SynchronizationContext.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
    }, null);

    // Do some work.
    await Task.Delay(2000);

    // Report progress to the UI.
    sc.Send(state =>
    {
      Time_SynchronizationContext.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
    }, null);

    // Do some work.
    await Task.Delay(2000);

    // Report progress to the UI.
    sc.Send(state =>
    {
      Time_SynchronizationContext.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
    }, null);
  },
  CancellationToken.None,
  TaskCreationOptions.None,
  TaskScheduler.Default)
  .ConfigureAwait(false)
  .GetAwaiter()
  .GetResult()
  .ContinueWith(_ =>
  {
    sc.Post(state =>
    {
      Status_SynchronizationContext.Text = "Finished";
    }, null);
  });
}
```

Notice this time through, we dont need to rely on external objects for synchronizing between threads. We are, in fact, synchronizing between *contexts*.

Now, even though you didn't ask, but for the sake of completeness, there is one more way to accomplish what you want in an abstracted way without the need for the **`SynchronizationContext`** object or using the **`Dispatcher`**. Since we are already using the TPL (Task Parallel Library) for our task handling, we could just use the task scheduler as follows:

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void Start_Via_TaskScheduler_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Time_TaskScheduler.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");


  // This TaskScheduler captures SynchronizationContext.Current.
  var taskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
  Status_TaskScheduler.Text = "Started";

  // Start a new task (this uses the default TaskScheduler, 
  // so it will run on a ThreadPool thread).
  Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
  {
    // We are running on a ThreadPool thread here.

    // Do some work.
    await Task.Delay(2000);

    // Report progress to the UI.
    var reportProgressTask = ReportProgressTask(taskScheduler, () =>
    {
      Time_TaskScheduler.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
      return 90;
    });

    // get result from UI thread
    var result = reportProgressTask.Result;
    Debug.WriteLine(result);

    // Do some work.
    await Task.Delay(2000); // Do some work.

    // Report progress to the UI.
    reportProgressTask = ReportProgressTask(taskScheduler, () =>
      {
        Time_TaskScheduler.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
        return 10;
      });

    // get result from UI thread
    result = reportProgressTask.Result;
    Debug.WriteLine(result);

    // Do some work.
    await Task.Delay(2000); // Do some work.

    // Report progress to the UI.
    reportProgressTask = ReportProgressTask(taskScheduler, () =>
    {
      Time_TaskScheduler.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
      return 340;
    });

    // get result from UI thread
    result = reportProgressTask.Result;
    Debug.WriteLine(result);
  }, 
  CancellationToken.None,
  TaskCreationOptions.None,
  TaskScheduler.Default)
    .ConfigureAwait(false)
    .GetAwaiter()
    .GetResult()
    .ContinueWith(_ =>
    {
      var reportProgressTask = ReportProgressTask(taskScheduler, () =>
      {
        Status_TaskScheduler.Text = "Finished";
        return 0;
      });
      reportProgressTask.Wait();
    });
}

/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="taskScheduler"></param>
/// <param name="func"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private Task<int> ReportProgressTask(TaskScheduler taskScheduler, Func<int> func)
{
  var reportProgressTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(func,
    CancellationToken.None,
    TaskCreationOptions.None,
    taskScheduler);
  return reportProgressTask;
}
```

As they say, there is more than one way to schedule a task ; )

Comment: Great answer. Very well explained.

Answer (score 6):

`SynchronizationContext` is an abstraction that uses virtual methods. Using  `SynchronizationContext` allows you don't tie your implementation to a specific framework.

Example: Windows Forms uses the `WindowsFormSynchronizationContext` that overrides Post to call `Control.BeginInvoke`. WPF uses the `DispatcherSynchronizationContext` type that overrides Post to call `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`. You can design your component that uses `SynchronizationContext` and doesn't tie implementation to a particular framework.

Answer (score 3):

The `Dispatcher` class is useful when you’re sure that you are calling within the context of the user interface thread and the `SynchronizationContext` is useful when you're not quite sure.

If you obtain your `Dispatcher` class using the `static Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` method on some non-UI thread and call the `BeginInvoke` method, nothing will happen (No exception, no warning, nada).

However, if you obtain your `SynchronizationContext` class via the static `SynchronizationContext.Current` method, it will return null if the thread is not a UI thread. This feather is very useful because it allows you to react to both a UI thread and a non-UI thread accordingly.